# FCKeditor uploads but doesn't show in the folder?

Tags: image, upload, fckeditor

When i use the file browser to upload the image it shows it's in the correct folder but when I physically check the folder the image isn't there. When I "browse server" it shows the image is still there and I can put the image in the window.

any idea why the image isn't actually there?

Also, if i try to delete the folder I used to upload to windows tells me: "Cannot remove foldoer *****: The directory is not empty"

FCKeditor has had some affect on the folder but it's completely empty.

Answer (score 1):

Try checking your folder permissions. I've had similar problems in the past but it was a permissions issue not anything to do with the WYSIWYG editor.

This is especially the case with IIS (yuk!).

Comment: I'm using windows to set my permissions but I have the folders I'm uploading set to full permissions on users and IIS users.

Comment: If i go to the address for the image i can see it:

www.site.com/folder/imagename.png

However, if i go to the physical folder it shows that is empty. It's not a hidden file either.

Comment: If I drag the file to the folder windows tells me the file exists and asks if I want to replace it.

for example, if i upload image.png to the sports folder. The editor shows it in the folder and I can add it to the editor window as expected. If I go to the image's address in the browser it will show. However if i go to physical folder the image is not there. If i try to add in to the sports folder by dragging in there windows says it exists and asks if i want to override the file.

Also, if I add files outside of FCKeditor I can see them in the editor and use them just like the others.